# SQL Server 2014 Install Not Creating Default Instance

Tags: instance

I am trying to install SQL Server 2014. The problem that I am having is that during the installation it is not letting my choose whether I want to use a default or a named instance. I have been through SQL Server Configuration Manager and under services there is nothing listed. I have tried this install with both 2014 express and enterprise on three PCs, two windows 8.1 and win 7. All three results are the same.

When at the "Connect to Server" at the start of Management Studio, there is nothing listed in the server name field. When I go to browse for more there is nothing listed in the local/network servers tab.

Is there anything that I need before the install? I have been searching for answers for about 3 days. Very few with the same issue. Any help would be appreciated.

**Note - This is a repost from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914930/sql-server-2014-install-not-creating-default-instance. Posting it here as this would be the more correct side.